# After install mod_security and mod_evasive, php not working

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, mod-security

I followed this tutorial ( tutorial.centos.com.my/?p=69 ) and got success to install mod_security and mod_evasive. But php does not run, displays the code in the browser. Insert an index.php file in EC2 disk with the php code **phpinfo ();** but this is ignored and the EC2 displays the **Amazon Linux AMI Test Page** page. I did several tests but nothing works. Does anyone know a way to run php?

Comment: @Roobie Please confirm below:

Confirm with: 

#rpm -q php

Any customization of /etc/httpd/httpd.conf somehow disable Apache's ability to server php content? Check for  errors in apache error.log

Comment: I corrected this by changing **DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var** to **DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.html.var** of /etc/httpd/httpd.conf